# ASP.NET Bootstrap Navigation Bar Styling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

This is a very simple question. I have seen this example of a navigation bar and I would like to do something similar https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/pricing/.

When I copy the code

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Company name</h5>
  <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Enterprise</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Support</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </nav>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Sign up</a>
</div>
```

To my `_layout.cshtml` file to get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <environment names="Development">
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
        <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Company name</h5>
        <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Enterprise</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Support</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </nav>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Sign up</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This does not render like the example. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of Bootstrap!

Specifically, the code you copied for the nav bar is from version 4 of Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/pricing/, note the **4.1** in the url), but the libraries you are calling in are for version 3.3.6. These versions are not compatible, you need to pick one or the other.

At least that what it looks like, I'm not sure what is in your 'css' bundle that you are calling for development, but for staging and production you are calling on https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css, again, note the **3.3.6**

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for your time. I am not a web-developer, you might be able to tell! :]